# System of equations involving 3 variables , whether it it solvable for real values of k

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Can anyone confirm if I am correct for this question, thank you.

There are positive real numbers $x$ and $y$ which solve the equations $2x + ky = 4, \;x + y = k$,for
(a) all values of $k$
(b) no values of $k$
(c) $k = 2$ only 
(d) only $k > −2$.

**My attempt**: $$k-y=x\\2(k-y)+ky=4\\2k+ky-2y=4\\k(2+y)=4+2y\\2+y=4+2y\implies y=-2\\k=4+2(-2)\implies k=0$$
There is a problem with my solution. $y$ is a positive real value, and my answer is not correct. I suspect it is line 4 - can I not treat $k$ as a factor similar to factorising quadratics?

Comment: First of all, what you presented is not a solution (attempted or otherwise) because this is a multiple-choice question, and you didn't choose a, b, c, or d!

Also, it's hard to understand what's happening in your work. For example, how do you go from $k(2+y) = 4+2y$ to $2+y = 4+2y$? This is only a valid step if $k = 1$, which is certainly not something you already deduced (indeed it cannot be deduced from the equations given). You should explain what you're doing in complete sentences so that we can try to understand your thought process.

Comment: Do you know how to solve a system of linear equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints for solving the problem:**

You have $2k+ky-2y=4$, which means $y(k-2)=-2k+4$.

Solve for $y$ if $k\ne 2$.

And can you see that, if $k=2$, then all real numbers $x$ and $y$ solve the equations?